# Is there a way to use underline, bold and Italic in a single cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to the VBA world. I was wondering if there is any way that you could use underline, bold and Italic in a single cell. In this example, I would like just the first and second line to be bold, with the name coming 2 hyphens after the first word, and the third line underline. Not entirely sure if this is possible. The first cell shows what I have. The second cell shows what I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: Are there 2 breaks in every cell?

Comment: You can record a macro of you doing these things and then see what it does with the functions etc. Then work it from there.

Otherwise are you doing this to a single selected cell at a time or is it a range of cells?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for yours and @shrivallabha.redij help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to perform this on several cells then you can use below code as a starting point. I have provided comments in the code which should assist you to understand.

```
Public Sub HUBSpecificStyle()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim varContent, varFirstRow
    
    '\\Loop through all cells in selection
    For Each rng In Range("A2:B2") '\\ Set your range reference here
        varContent = Split(rng.Value, Chr(10)) '\\ Split cell contents by newline character
        With rng
            '\\ First two lines of row bold
            .Characters(1, Len(varContent(0) & Chr(10) & varContent(1))).Font.Bold = True
            '\\Third line underline
            .Characters(Len(varContent(0) & Chr(10) & varContent(1) & Chr(10)) + 1, Len(varContent(2))).Font.Underline = True
            '\\ Split first line with hyphens
            varFirstRow = Split(varContent(0), "-")
            '\\Third part italic
            .Characters(Len(varFirstRow(0) & "-" & varFirstRow(1) & "-") + 1, Len(varFirstRow(2))).Font.Italic = True
        End With
    Next rng

End Sub
```